# Output of Multiple Select Statement In Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple query which is providing count based on different where condition.

Will it be possible to bring all result in single Rows.

for eg:

```
Query1: 
SELECT COUNT(COL25) ASSURED, FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1= 'ALPHA' AND COL2='ROLE'

Query2:
SELECT COUNT(COL25) RELEASE FROM TAB1 WHERE COL3 in('BEETA','X','Y') AND COLSTATUS='ABC'

The result for 1st query is ASSURED = 100
and 2nd Query is RELEASE = 5000
```

i am trying to display output as

```
ASSURED  | RELEASE
100      | 5000
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sql 2012

Comment: "SQL" is a query language not a DBMS, but as there is no such standard as "SQL 2012" it's safe to assume that you mean "SQL **Server** 2012"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: my bad. u r right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use joins, but @Gordon Linoff answer is cleaner and way shorter than this.

```
SELECT first.ASSURED, second.RELEASE
FROM
    (SELECT
         COUNT(COL25) ASSURED
    FROM TAB1 
    WHERE COL1= 'ALPHA' AND COL2='ROLE') AS first
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                 COUNT(COL25) RELEASE 
             FROM TAB1 
             WHERE COL3 in('BEETA','X','Y') 
             AND COLSTATUS='ABC') AS second
         ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 'ALPHA' AND COL2 = 'ROLE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as ASSURED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COL3 = 'BEETA' AND COLSTATUS = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RELEASE
FROM TAB1;
```

EDIT:

If you actually need to count non-NULL values, you can be explicit (my preference):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COL1 = 'ALPHA' AND COL2 = 'ROLE' AND col25 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as ASSURED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COL3 = 'BEETA' AND COLSTATUS = 'ABC' AND col25 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RELEASE
FROM TAB1;
```

Or be a bit more implicit:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN COL1 = 'ALPHA' AND COL2 = 'ROLE' THEN col25 END) as ASSURED,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN COL3 = 'BEETA' AND COLSTATUS = 'ABC' THEN col25 END) as RELEASE
FROM TAB1;
```

Comment: It won't work if multiple checks in where clause, i've edited the question.

Can we apply pivot in this scenario Please suggest

Comment: @RohiniMathur, it will work indeed, just modify the case expression: CASE WHEN COL3 IN ('BEETA','X','Y') AND COLSTATUS = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: @JesúsLópez: But i have to do count on col25

Comment: @RohiniMathur. Same thing, modify the case expression: CASE WHEN COL25 IS NOT NULL AND COL3 IN ('BEETA','X','Y') AND COLSTATUS = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END